# Summing up all the nodes a tree with a generic type. (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to write a code which takes all the integers in a tree and return a sum of them. I'm trying to do this with type `a`, which is from a data time:

`data Tree a = Nil | Value a (Tree a) (Tree a)
 deriving Show`

and we want to use:
`tree = Value 2 (Value 2 (Value 2 Nil Nil) Nil) (Value 2 Nil Nil)`

and my code is as follow:

```
countTree :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> Tree a -> a
countTree p k (Nil) = h
countTree p k (Value x y z) = x (+) (countTree p k y) (+) (countTree p k z)
```

and I want to run my code as `countTree (+) 0 tree` and the results should return `8`. 
The problem is that when I run my code it tells me that `x` has four arguments but it's type `a` has zero which I honestly don't understand why. I've modifying sections of my code, but no success once so ever, I could really use some assistance.

Answer (score 3):

```
x (+) (countTree p k y) (+) (countTree p k z)
```

is attempting to treat `x` as a function, and pass to it as arguments all of

```
(+) (countTree p k y) (+) (countTree p k z)
```

If you want to have "x + recur left + recur right", you'd want something like:

```
x + (countTree p k y) + (countTree p k z)
```

I'm pretty sure however you actually want to use `p`, not `+` hard coded. Using prefix notation, you'd have to rearrange it a bit to something like :

```
(p (p x (countTree p k y)) (countTree p k z))
```

Or, you could use backticks to inline the calls to `p` as @bipll suggested:

```
x `p` (countTree p k y) `p` (countTree p k z)
```

---

A side note, but I'm also pretty sure you want `h` to be `k`.

Comment: Or simply `x \`p\` (countTree p k y) \`p\` (countTree p k z)`.

Comment: @bipll Yes. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @bipll Oh, and just an FYI, you seem to have escaped your backticks using backslashes. You can put backticks in inlined code by surrounding the code in double backticks. Might be easier of there are a lot of backticks in the code.

Comment: It’s kind of uncommon, but just as a curiosity, it’s also possible to give a symbolic name to a parameter and then use it as a local operator, e.g., `countTree (%) k (Value x y z) = x % countTree (%) p k y % countTree (%) k z` where `%` can be whatever operator name you want. And since the operation `p`/`(%)` and the base value `k` are repeated on every call, this function also benefits from factoring the recursive bits into a helper function: `countTree (%) k = go where { go Nil = k; go (Value x y z) = x % go y % go z }`